# What does "ad_play_t" in pocketsphinx?

Tags: playback, pocketsphinx

I was searching for `ad_rec_start()` that I found there is `ad_start_play()` function too. But I couldn't understand what exactly this function n do? Can I play `.wav` files with this? Or it's a text-to-speech engine like `espeak` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can play audio file with it. Long time ago the library was used in TTS like flite, but later TTS and ASR implementations diverged and the method become redundant.